# Part of Log4Net log missing in WCF Service Async method call

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, log4net

I am writing a WCF service (library) that is being called for testing from a Console application. Everything worked swimmingly when I was running tests in a linear fashion, but as soon as I tried to make a few calls async, it appears that the logging starts at the 3rd instance, and then I see elements of the first two calls sprinkled into the log, with chunks of the first two items logging entirely missing. It is if Log4net deletes everything from the log each time a new call is made to MyMethod.

Console app code looks like this:

```
var x = new MyClient();
x.MyMethodAsync(params);
x.MyMethodAsync(params);
x.MyMethodAsync(params);
```

My WCF service has Log4Net in it. In the WCF Service, I have the Logger defined as such:

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Then in the WCF Service (MyMethod), I have:

```
if (!LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

I added the "if" statement wondering if the Configuration call was somehow causing Log4net to wipe the entire file, but that is not is as it properly appends to an existing log, just missing parts of the first two async calls logging.

I will add additional info if anyone has questions.

My log4net file looks something like this:

```
* first line of 3rd call to WCF Service
* second line of 3rd call to WCF Service
* third line of 1st call to WCF Service
* second line of 2nd call to WCF Service
* third line of 2nd call to WCF Service
* third line of 3rd call to WCF Service
```

This is simplified for point, but the first few log4net calls to the 1st and 2nd call are not making it into the log at all. They do when I call this wcf method synchronously.

Comment: Can you add enough of your original code to reproduce this?

Comment: Can you show you configuration?